# sqlite: assert statement: getting name with highest value

Tags: python, sqlite

Note: Please feel free to share applicable resources. I have found it rather difficult.

I am attempting to write the following python function:

```
def player_with_max_points_per_game():
    """ The player with highest average points per game"""

    cur.execute('SELECT name, avg_points FROM players ORDER BY 
    avg_points')

    # Now I want to select 'name' from the top row
```

PS: I realize my intended approach might be inefficient. I saw there was a MAX() function. Any recommendations?

[Here is an image from my DB browser sorted by 'avg_points'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fCs0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the value of the first column.

```
cur.execute('SELECT name, avg_points FROM players ORDER BY avg_points DESC LIMIT 1')
row = cur.fetchone()
best_player_name = row[0]
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate this

Comment: Your thanks is appreciated... especially in the form of an upvote and accepted answer. :)

Comment: my ranking status doesn't allow upvotes unfortunately

Comment: No sweat, just being saucy. Cheers!